# JQuery mobile clear back button history

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have an app written by jquery mobile. It contains multiple pages, implementing a sequential flow and the back button on android phones works great for taking the user back.

But when the flow finishes, I want to return to the start page, and of course I don't want the user to be navigated to the last page by pressing the back button.

I wrote something like this, when the flow finishes:

```
$.mobile.navigate.history.stack = [];
$.mobile.changePage("#main", {transition: "pop"});
```

But the result is not the desired one. User will be navigated to the `#main` page, and when he/she presses the back button, he/she returns to the last page.

What is the problem?

Answer (score -2):

I believe you can just add `reverse: false` to your call to `changePage`

```
$.mobile.changePage("#main", {reverse: false, changeHash: false, transition: "pop"});
```